# c - connect() does not return

Tags: c, sockets, client

I'm trying to build a c client that sends an html request message to a website, and then reads the response. Unfortunately, my connect() statement does not return.

Yes, I have seen this answer: [connect() does not return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216462/connect-does-not-return)

However, I do not want to set the socket to non-blocking, and then keep doing select() until I get a response, as I am only dealing with one request at a time.

```
int main() {

    struct hostent *hp;
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;

    mySocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    hp = gethostbyname("firefox.com"));

    bzero((char *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)hp->h_addr_list[0], (char *)&serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr, hp->h_length);

    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(8080); // works up till here

    connect(mySocket, (SA *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)); // never returns

    return 0;
}
```

Am I connecting correctly? I've gotten rid of the error checking in the above code.

Here is the output of "lsof -Pnl +M -i4" in terminal

```
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
proxy   8321     1000    3u  IPv4  51542      0t0  TCP 10.0.2.15:42708->63.245.213.17:8080 (SYN_SENT)
```

Could this be a firewall issue? If so, how do I resolve it?

Comment: Usually this means the server isn't sending anything back (not even a "go away" packet) when your computer tries to connect, so your computer waits a few minutes for a response. Are you sure firefox.com is actually running a server on port 8080?

Comment: I tried port 80, it returned. Thank you!!

Comment: Just for testing: first try to connect to a local service(echo, telnet, smtp)

Comment: It *does* return, after at most a minute or two, but as you are ignoring the return value and failing nto print the error that occurred, you are never discovering why it failed. Don't write code like this, or make incorrect claims about it.

Comment: "*I do not want to set the socket to non-blocking, and then keep doing `select()` until I get a response*" - unless you are willing to wait until `connect()` times out on its own if the host can't be reached (which can take a long time), it is the best option. Set the socket to non-blocking, call `select()` *once* with a timeout, and if `select()` times out or otherwise fails then close the socket and move on, otherwise set the socket back to blocking if desired and then perform your subsequent I/O as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I should've been on port 80, not 8080, in the line:

```
serveraddr.sin_port = htons(8080); // no
serveraddr.sin_port = htons(80); // yes
```

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: this is not the reason. if port is wrong then connect function should return with -1 value but you say it isn't.